# `undefined reference to `sgtsv_'` when compiling a tridiagonal solver

Tags: fortran

I'm working on a problem for one of my computing courses and I was getting stuck in an error after trying to work through it for some time.

Specifically, I'm working on this Fortran routine:

```
program linsolve_sgtsv
implicit none
integer, parameter :: lda=10,ldb=lda,nrhs=1
real :: dl(lda-1),d(lda),du(lda-1),b(ldb,nrhs)
integer :: n,info

n = 10
dl(1:n-1) = 1+(1/11); d(1:n) = 2; du(1:n-1) = 1-(1/11)
b(1:n,1) = (/1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1/)
call sgtsv(n,nrhs,dl,d,du,b,ldb,info)
if (info==0) then
    print *, '--- x is ----------------'
    print '(g22.16)', b(1:n,1)
else
    print *, 'info = ',info
end if

end program linsolve_sgtsv
```

This routine solves linear systems using gaussian elimination when the matrices are tridiagonal.

However, when I try to create a makefile using:

```
gfortran linsolve_sgtsv.f90 -o linsolve.f90
```

I get the following errors:

```
tmp/ccCiRHve.o: In function `MAIN__':
linsolve_sgtsv.f90:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `sgtsv_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I don't think it is the problem, although naming the outputfile `.f90` is certainly a Bad Idea. I think Vishnu just doesn't link in LAPACK. At least fom looking at the file names. Just use `-llapack` and make sure LAPACK is installed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any direct duplicate. Many people have similar problems, but they usually know a bit more and your question is more basic.

The tridiagonal solver `sgtsv()` is not a Fortran built-in subroutine. It is provided in a library called LAPACK and many other implementations (e.g., MKL). That means you must tell the compiler it should include (link) that library.

That is done by adding `-llapack` (`-l` means "link" and `lapack` is the name of the library which is stored in a file called `liblapack.so` or `liblapack.a`) at the end of the compile command.

You must have his library installed in your computer for the link flag to work. In many Linux distributions it is included in the repositories.

The correct line would be

```
gfortran linsolve_sgtsv.f90 -o linsolve -llapack
```

If the library (`liblapack.a` or `liblapack.so`) is installed in some directory the compiler can't see, you must use

```
gfortran linsolve_sgtsv.f90 -o linsolve -L/path/to/liblapack -llapack
```

See also [gfortran LAPACK "undefined reference" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669410/gfortran-lapack-undefined-reference-error) and your compiler's manual for more.

---

Notice I did `-o linsolve` instead of `-o linsolve.f90`. It is a very bad idea to name your executable file with a `.f90` extension. Only Fortran source files should be named `.f90`.

---

There will be more problems in your code. They will appear when you start to test it. For example, yoy do

```
 (1/11)
```

this will not return the mathematical result of 1.0/11.0, it will return 0. Learn about integer division in Fortran. See [Why are the elements of an array formatted as zeros when they are multiplied by 1/2 or 1/3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488518/why-are-the-elements-of-an-array-formatted-as-zeros-when-they-are-multiplied-by/24488741#24488741) and [Simple program, that only produce zeros, bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40314735/simple-program-that-only-produce-zeros-bug/40314894#40314894)

If you will find more problems after you can run your code, you can ask a new question.

I recommend to compile your programs with `-g -fcheck=all -Wall` to find more bugs and errors more easily.